# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: '[JavaScript Error: "a is null

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I have a 2 situations to execute the javascript functionality:

Case 1 - to get the XXXXX information from iframe using executeScript() and save it in global variable 
--> Refresh the iframe.

Case 2 - using that XXXXX information again I need to use executeScript().

Here I can get the result for Case 1. But when case 2 is executed then it HANGS.. any idea?

Thanks & Regards
Ramesh Kumar

Comment: Can you please provide more information like what javascript you are trying to execute? In general, iframes are tricky in particular if they are from a different domain than the top frame.

Comment: Please provide more information. It is better to provide HTML code also

Comment: String jsStatement = "return Application.IL0.getUserData(\""+rowId+"\",\"processId\");";String processId =  (String) jse.executeScript(jsStatement);then i called Refresh the frame  
public void  getRefreshSeed () { 
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();   driver.switchTo().frame(this.getWorkbasketSeed()); 
  driver.findElement(By.id("refresh")).click();
  this.setbRefresh(true);
  System.out.println(this.bRefresh);
  this.waitForWorkbasketLoad(); }String jsStatement = "return Application.IL0.getUserData(\""+rowId+"\",\"processId\");";String processId =  (String) jse.executeScript(jsStatement);

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3499
try to DISMISS the alert

```
<code>
driver.execute(Command.DISMISS_ALERT)
</code>
```